# Rails get data for last 24hrs starting at 9am

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have data that provides rainfall every 1 hour. The problem I'm facing is that it records the days rainfall from 9am to 8:30am the next day. How can I best query this certain timeframe using Postgres in Rails 5?

So far, I'm grouping by the timestamp (which is the date + time) and selecting a starting time of 9am, but where I fall short is informing the query to go to the next day at 8:30am before the rainfall data refreshes for the next day.

```
@rainfall = Weather.select('DATE(timestamp) as timestamp, MAX(rain) as maxrain')
.group(:timestamp).where("timestamp::time BETWEEN '9:00:00' AND '8:30:00'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that your day starts at 9:00 and ends at 8:30 the next day, it's good to have a scope for your data.

Example:

```
scope :for_day, -> (day) {
  date_time_from = Time.zone.parse("#{day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} 9:00")
  date_time_to = Time.zone.parse("#{(day + 1.day).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} 8:30")

  where(timestamp: (date_time_from..date_time_to))
}
```

Usage:

`Weather.for_day(1.day.ago)` will return: `08 May 2019 9:00 AM till 09 May 2019 8:30 AM`

and you can then do whatever you want with the data (ex: group and max)

---

## EDIT

Based on the comments, I assume that you want to get all the data. That being said, it's better to add a new column to your table that has the day in it.

#### Migration

```
add_column :weathers, :day
add_index :weathers, :day
```

#### Weather.rb

```
class Weather < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :set_date

  scope :for_day, -> (day) {
    where(day: day)
  }

  def self.dates_for_day(day)
    date_time_from = Time.zone.parse("#{day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} 9:00")
    date_time_to = Time.zone.parse("#{(day + 1.day).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} 8:30")

    return {
      day: day,
      from: date_time_from,
      to: date_time_to
    }
  end

  private

  def set_day
    # get the surrounding days to know which day to use
    surrounding_days = [
      Weather.dates_for_day(self.timestamp - 1.day),
      Weather.dates_for_day(self.timestamp),
      Weather.dates_for_day(self.timestamp + 1.day),
    ]

    self.day = surrounding_days.select { |d| self.timestamp.between?(d[:from], d[:to]) }.first[:day]
  end
end
```

Now you can query / group your data in the way you want

Comment: Thanks @Roc. This works, but only for the current day. would it be because of Weather.for_day(1.day.ago).

Comment: @DollarChills correct; if you need more days you’ll have to call them too: Weather.for_day(2.days.ago); etc...

Comment: Anyway to call this on all days?